# Sum function from the data-* attribute inside a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have to obtain a sum from the contents of data-value attributes in a table.
The table it's created dynamically row by row with an onclick function in javascript with .append (each click append a row and pass data-valore to the row and a text inside the ).

The table start in this way:

```
<table id="franco">
<tr><th id="valore"> Total value </th></tr>
</table>
```

And it's "populated" like this:

```
<table id="franco">
<tbody>
<tr><th id="valore"> Total value</th></tr>
<tr><td class="pick" data-valore="7">Frank Zappa</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pick" data-valore="3">Mozart</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pick" data-valore="10">Roger Waters</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pick" data-valore="11">Zu</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pick" data-valore="7">Maserati</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I sum all the valor in "data-valore" and show this result inside the th row?

EDIT: 
The function must refresh the sum every time the table it's updated with another row. The id of the onclick it's #scelta1 (id="scelta1"), the same function for the row creation it's on other 17 div (scelta1, scelta2, scelta3 ... scelta18). It's tricky!

EDIT 2: I have a solution, maybe can be handy for someone else:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#scelta').on('click', function () {
var sum = 0;
$(".pick").each(function(){
sum += parseInt($(this).data("valore"));
});
$('#sum').text(sum);
});
});
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Thanks, very handy solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This it's the way I like it!

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#scelta').on('click', function () {
var sum = 0;
$(".pick").each(function(){
sum += parseInt($(this).data("valore"));
});
$('#sum').text(sum);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query all the elements with the attribute `data-valore`, map them into numbers, and then add them up.

```js
var total = [].slice
  .call(document.querySelectorAll('#franco [data-valore]'))
  .map(el => Number(el.getAttribute('data-valore')))
  .reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  });

document
  .getElementById('valore')
  .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', total);
```

```html
<table id="franco">
  <tbody>
    <tr><th id="valore">Total value: </th></tr>
    <tr><td class="pick" data-valore="7">Frank Zappa</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="pick" data-valore="3">Mozart</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="pick" data-valore="10">Roger Waters</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="pick" data-valore="11">Zu</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="pick" data-valore="7">Maserati</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand why my result is NaN!

Comment: @FlaivoLuminolZanardi, can you create either a code snippet in your question, or a JSFiddle?

Comment: I've just copied your code inside a <script></script>, maybe it's because the data-valore attribute is also in other part of the page? (the table rows it's created onclick, one by one, with a js jquery function and take various "data"  to set the attribute to the row). I'm a noob, I know and english it's not my mother tongue!

Comment: @FlaivoLuminolZanardi: Hm, that is strange, I've updated the selector in my answer to use the id for the table in the query: `#franco [data-valore]`, I wonder if that would help

Comment: It works if the table is already present in the page, I've tried to add some row with value and the function result correct but not in my case :(

Comment: @FlaivoLuminolZanardi, have you tried wrapping your code in a listener for when the page loads?
`window.addEventListener('load', function () {... rest of code here})`. Or maybe it needs to go in the callback for your click handler? Sounds like the table is created dynamically, which would mean you'd want to run that code over again after each append.

Comment: I think this way it's not for me :( If I put this code inside the function that create the row of the table it will work but it "append" the result one after one, example: 1 - 2 - 3= 123, and the creation of that table depends on 18 identical function because I have 18 place for the user chiose, so every onclick function can create a table row... it's a mess for a noob like me...

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using jQuery, check this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var sum = 0;
  $("#franco .pick").each(function(){
    var value =  $(this).data("valore");
    sum = sum + value;
    
    $("#franco #sum").text(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="franco">
<tbody>
<tr><th id="valore"> Total value <span id="sum"></span></th></tr>
<tr><td class="pick" data-valore="7">Frank Zappa</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pick" data-valore="3">Mozart</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pick" data-valore="10">Roger Waters</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pick" data-valore="11">Zu</td></tr>
<tr><td class="pick" data-valore="7">Maserati</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This work, but only on a static table, my table it's created dynamically row by row!